# How do I force "vw" units to obey the html meta "viewport" tag width setting?

Tags: html, css

Currently, when I use CSS "vw" units (viewport width), the browser seems to always use the browser viewport, regardless of what the meta viewport is. For example, please see this jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/darrengates/ywvc6x51/

In this example, I have:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=75, initial-scale=1">
```

In the css, if I specify:

```
.vw-75 {
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Then, I'm hoping to force any content with the "vw-75" class to be 75px, since the meta viewport is set to "width=75". Is there any way that I can force "vw" units to obey the meta value?

For those wondering "why would you ever want to do this?":

> I have a website that uses VW units all over the place (for font sizes, div sizes, border sizes, etc.). Due to the requirements of the website, I want the maximum viewable area to be different based on browser, device, language, etc. In other words, the viewable content area might be anywhere from about 500px to 2000px. Rather than change all of the vw values to % values, or add a ton of new media queries (a huge task due to the site size), I'm hoping to just dynamically set the meta viewport.

Comment: What is the use case for this?  It's unclear why you'd want to do this?

Comment: I have a website that uses VW units all over the place (for font sizes, div sizes, border sizes, etc.). Due to the requirements of the website, I want the maximum viewable area to be different based on browser, device, language, etc. In other words, the viewable content area might be anywhere from about 500px to 2000px. Rather than change all of the vw values to % values, or add a ton of new media queries (a huge task due to the site size), I'm hoping to just dynamically set the meta viewport.

Comment: "VW units all over the place (for font sizes, div sizes, border sizes, etc.)" - please stop. just stop. respect your users, please!

Comment: Dai - whether or not using vw units was a good idea, this is the situation that is currently present, which I have to work with.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that Chrome (at least) is paying attention to the `<meta name="viewport">` tag unless I'm using the responsive design mode.

Comment: I tried responsive design mode in Chrome, but the result is the same... seems like this meta tag is just ignored (or, I'm badly misinterpreting it!)

Comment: I don't think you can explicitly set the viewport on desktop browsers because it is defined by the size of the window. It works on mobiles because they use a virtual viewport that can be different than the physical pixel size.

Answer (score 1):

[Try removing `, initial-scale=1` from your meta tag:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag#Viewport_basics)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=75">
```

The problem may simply be that jsfiddle doesn't apply the `<meta>` tag.

Comment: Blazemonger - I tried that, but no luck unfortunately. I created a "test.html" file on my desktop with the same code as in jsfiddle, but set the meta to what you suggested (without initial-scale) and the result was the same. It seems like this meta value is just ignored. Same result for Firefox and Safari, too.

Comment: That's not work.